# Terminal Git tracking vs VS Code git tracking is not in sync

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

When I add, modify OR delete files from Terminal (I am using iTerm2 -oh my zsh- git extension) stage them and commit them it doesn't reflect in my VS code git tracking.

My source control section in VS code still says that changes are not staged OR tracked with git.
And I have to stage and commit them again.

When I open terminal in VS code and check `git config --list`, both iTerm2 terminal and VS code terminal shows same list of configuration.

Also log and history is also same when I check from both individual terminals.

It's just when I stage OR commit from either of my iterm2 terminal OR from VS Code, they both don't consider changes are staged OR committed if other terminal did, and still shows untracked OR not committed of each others.

Did any one face such issue before? Is anything to do with VS Code Git settings or so?

[image: See screenshot exact error i am mentioning]

Comment: What happens if you edit the file in one, and then view it in the other? Can you see the edits you made from the other one even without `git status` showing any changes?

Comment: Yes i can see changes in file

Answer (score 2):

> Did any one face such issue before?

No, and if you actually make *another* commit with VSCode, after making one with iTerm2, there is no way, the `git log` would show you identical commits (SHA1), since part of a commit metadata is its creation date.

Try and add [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens), to see more information on your local Git repository.

Check also for any `GIT_xxx` environment variable (like ones regarding [Repository location](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_repository_locations) -- `GIT_DIR`, `GIT_WORK_TREE`) which might explain why a Git repository is not seen by default.

Comment: it does, see screenshot added in original question. Thank you for gitLens ref and commands. I will try those to see if there is any issue with my configuration.

Comment: @VaibhavChawale The `git status` is indeed different, but I was referring to two `git commit`, which would give you two different SHA1.

Comment: Hi @VonC - I am getting two different results for "git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT" command. Both results have same username and email id but numerical value is different. First one is "1625420409 -0500" and second one is "1625337346 -0500". Do you know what does that mean? Do i need to update gitconfig or something to make both terminal authors same?

Comment: @VaibhavChawale Those should be the same. Try a `git config -l --show-scope --show-origin` in both environments, and see if Git is referring to the same set of config files for both.

Comment: both returns same value.

Comment: @VaibhavChawale Then I don't think `git val` timestamps difference is relevant here.

Comment: Adding GitLens worked for me